# Node.js Express response is ended before Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Executing following code on Node.js with Express, but it does not return anything. It looks like res.send does not work from within promise.then(); Looks like it already returned back to the caller before promise resolve(); What I'm doing wrong? According to examples, it should work. Thanks.

```
    const express = require('express');
    const app = express();

    app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
      res.send("Good");  // Works Just Fine , but I dont need to return here
      getMessage().then(function(data){
          console.log("I'm here"); // Message works
          res.send("Good");  // Does not Work 
        }).catch(function(error){
          res.send("Error");
      });
    });

    function getMessage(){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){        
           setTimeout(function() {
            resolve();
    }, 3000);
        });    
    }
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
console.log("run");
});
```

[image: Response]

Comment: The <pre> and </pre> lines are part of your code or just a copy/paste error? If they are part of your code then you have to delete them.

Comment: <pre> removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Please add following code to your app: [Refer Here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html)

This app starts a server and listens on port 8080 for connections

```
app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 8080!')
```

})

Comment: I do listen to a port, I have updated the original post with a code. And Express res.send() works just fine without promises. The problem appears only if I do it from within promise.then(); Thanks.

Comment: can u give me the node's version? because i tried, it works for me

Comment: Node v6.11.3. How are you sending the request? I'm testing with Postman and Firefox Rest client. Maybe I'm missing to send some headers? Thanks.

Comment: I use postman too, take a look a pic
http://prntscr.com/h0qouc
http://prntscr.com/h0qp7f

Comment: Thank you. Should be some local issue on my side.

Comment: The problem was in request timeout setting in Postman that I'm using for testing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen on a port for the express server to run.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
  getMessage().then(function(data){
      res.send("Good");  
    }).catch(function(error){
      res.send("Error");
  });
});

function getMessage() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {        
       setTimeout(function() {
        resolve();
       }, 3000);
    });    
}

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App listening at http://localhost:${port}`));
```

Comment: I do listen to a port, I have updated the original post with a code. And Express res.send() works just fine without promises. The problem appears only if I do it from within promise.then(); Thanks.

Comment: For your promise, what are you resolving?

Comment: Does it matter? In reality, I'm resolving response body of asynchronous  API call.The code in this question just simplicity/example. Resolve works.  The problem that if I use {res} within {.then} it does not work.  Looks like the response is ended before Promise Resolve. Thanks.

Comment: The problem was in request timeout setting in Postman that I'm using for testing. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in request timeout setting in Postman that I'm using for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first

```
res.send('good');
```

or you could **res.write()** first
then the message should be concatenated when **res.send()**

```
res.write('good')
```

res.send() **closes** the connection between the server and client
therefore using res.write() will **write the message** and when res.send() is sent all the written messages **(using res.write())** are sent back to the client called

**IN SHORT** 
**res.write()** can happen several times 
**res.send()** happens once only per request